# Tracking the wallet owner of stolen bitcoins

Tags: privacy, theft

Hello Recently my bitcoin wallet was hacked and the money was transferred out into another bitcoin wallet. Is it possible to track and find out the owner of this wallet

Answer (score 0):

Every Bitcoin transaction is traceable, but... unfortunately, it is not possible to determine who owns the address. Unless somebody admit to having a particular address.