# Wallet forensic

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet

Someone who scammed me used this wallet to receive the BTC 12fmomENb5SSxR54Bitua71CZrc4oVQtmB he hasn't moved them from there since July 31st I'm trying to figure it if that wallet belong to any exchange so I can contact them because I have all proof that this person in fact stole from me...

Answer (score 1):

I analyzed a bit with forensic tools and found that with high likelihood either you or the scammer (or both) have an Huobi.com account.

If I understand you right then [03281a511f38992dff51dee176c66dfc5f873e92cd76228956ca5099a27214fd](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/03281a511f38992dff51dee176c66dfc5f873e92cd76228956ca5099a27214fd) shows the scam transaction and the input addresses on the left side are yours and you initiated the transaction?

If yes then wait until the funds of 12fmomENb5SSxR54Bitua71CZrc4oVQtmB move (as of writing no move), then the flow can be analyzed until the scammer cashes out by sending the funds to a known exchange address.

If no (hacker initiated the transaction): Then address 14trBCQy7eGqGHKTouGC24vFJoFBoofBmn belongs as well likely to the scammer (you should know it if you look into your wallet), address 1BAyMWsePjFXjURd7EAPxs7YzFZAnTuw8e belongs likely to the same person and sent some funds to address 19LoQjvaNvTtKeADkZfqsbWCkWqoyjsTiK which is a known Huobi.com address. In this case it depends on your and spammers jurisdiction and Huobi support and a bit luck if you can identify the spammer with police's help or legal action.

Wish you success!

**Update Nov 19,2020**:
The coins were moved and the 12fmomENb5SSxR54Bitua71CZrc4oVQtmB had a co-spend with address 12qVmVXgFEtimhPDEMuUdg4AApdgW4gUS4 which deposited and withdrew very likely in other transactions at poloniex.com. The same person very likely received a lot of BTC from bittrex.com . The BTC address 12qVmVXgFEtimhPDEMuUdg4AApdgW4gUS4 sent funds to BTC address 1DfYET2tnEU54K9r5hWxxb8dWr4uko9eP9 which belongs to bitfinex.com. The BTC address 1JEd1Nb5LXYVFiR9s1ZtXFdxvTKAYYCHNg (belonging likely to the same person) sent funds to BTC address 1PsXn2nruFCS2WCVedVo76yPGgaS6UXUrA which belongs to yobit.net .
So if you didn't receive your funds back in the meantime I'd try to involve law enforcement because the loss was not a low amount. The exchanges know if the scammer cashed out (bank account or id available) or if he exchanged into another coin to follow up from there. If the scammer was smart you won't succeed but it's difficult not to leave any traces.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In general, there's no way to know if that address belongs to an exchange.

This is especially true when the funds have not been moved/spent.

Similar questions:

- [Tracking the wallet owner of stolen bitcoins](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/63137/13866)
- [Wrongly Transferred!](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70693/13866)
- [How can I confirm to whom the bitcoin address I sent a payment too?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74237/13866)